# Plotting 2 parameters function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot 2 functions in MATLAB.
First one is like this: X=[0.1 0.2 0.3]; Y=[5 4 1]; plot(X,Y);
and the second one that I want to plot on the last function at the same figure is $$x^{2}y+3x+4y^{2}=1$$
I really confused about that!!

Comment: You could do a contour plot:  [x,y]=ndgrid([0:0.01:0.4],[0:0.1:5]);contour(x,y,x.^2.*y+3*x+4*y.^2,[1 1]);

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem it should be really easy. For the first plot you do:

```
figure
X=[0.1 0.2 0.3]; 
Y=[5 4 1]; 
plot(X,Y);
hold on % This holds the lines you have already plot
```

For the second plot I suggest you to explicit the function $x^{2}y+3x+4y^{2}=1$ with respect to $y$ (i.e. $y = f(x)$) then you do (after the previous commands):

```
plot(X,f(X))
```

That should solve your problem.

Of course you can put labels and titles to the plot by doing:

```
xlabel('the label for the x axis')
ylabel('the label for the y axis')
title('The title you want for the plot')
```

I hope this helped you.